# Default Vs Custom Shortcuts

Tags: ide, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, customization

**In your IDE/editor of choice, do you use only the default shortcuts out of the box, or do you customize them?** One answer per response, and why you do.

In my programming career, I have come full swing around on this. I started out in emacs/vim on a terminal window with a bare-bones install, no customizations, then over time swung fully into completely customizing them both, getting them *just* right, such to the point that other emacs/vim users could not even work at them (changing movement keys, etc). More recently, I have been working in Eclipse, the JetBrains IDEs, Visual Studio, and I have continued to make heavy modifications to each, so that they all pretty much behave the same way across all my machines. Obviously, this takes some effort to maintain, and every new IDE means a whole slew of command learning and changing, and then some (like Visual Studio) don't have certain commands out of the box, so they require plug-ins to achieve the same functionality (grow selection, delete words by camelCase, etc).

To be fair, I am an above-average speed typist, and I can work productively in any of these IDEs, but I have started to yearn for the simplicity of just going back to straight vim shortcuts, and using simple vim plugins to make it work in my IDEs. Then, at least, all I would need if I wanted to change anything would be a single custom .vimrc.

Suggestions, ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my IDE, I use a slightly-customized version of the default keymap.  More of it is default than not.  I prefer using the default whenever possible: you learn it once, and then it's the same no matter where you need to use that same IDE (it's reasonably safe to assume that most installations have the default keymap, if they even let you change it at all)

My situation might be different than yours. In my previous positions, I used to code exclusively in vim. In my current position, I don't change IDE's often because I don't have to: 100% of my development is in one language, and I've been working at that position for several years now.

That being said, I did just change IDE's (from Zend Studio to PhpStorm, by the way) recently, so the only changes I've made to PhpStorm's default keymap are to make it more like the several Zend Studio shortcuts I couldn't bear to part with.

Otherwise, when I'm working with vim, I think in vim; when I'm working with PhpStorm, I think in PhpStorm. At this time, I don't think it's worth my time/effort to completely customize my keymap, any more than I already have. If you're working with multiple IDE's, your situation is probably quite different from mine.

Ultimately, I don't think you're going to find a "right" answer to this question. Nobody else knows your preferences or situation better than you do. It's a trade-off either way, whether you go the default or the customized route.  Use your best judgment and decide which way you're going to go, and be happy with that choice.

Best of luck in your development efforts!